# All debian instances and template in qubes are unable to display any application

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machine, upgrade, qubes

A few weeks ago I had updated my Qubes OS VMS as usual. After restart;

1. Debian 8 instances run and the work including template.
2. any application I open begins to open, I see a "bouncing" icon as though the window is about to load, it then disappears.
3. This happens with all apps and in all instances including the template itself
4. I am unable to update the template or the instances, they just hang `dom0` and Qubes VM manager.

Any advise greatly appreciate, this issue has lost me a lot of previously working VMS.

Answer (score 0):

First, change all AppVMs templates to Fedora 23, **so they wont be deleted** after removing of Debian 8 template. Consider making a backup of `/var/lib/qubes/` where all your VM data are stored.

**In dom0 terminal, type**

```
sudo yum remove qubes-template-debian-8
```

This will remove Debian 8 template installed by repo. You can now clean install new template by

```
sudo qubes-dom0-update qubes-template-debian-8
```

After `reboot`, everything should work.